# writing angularjs directive to track value change

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I have an input tag whose value is changed by jquery. but angularjs ng-change is not fired when Jquery changes It's value. What can be reason?

```
<div ng-controller="daterangeCtrl">
    <input type="text" ng-model="period" ng-change="periodChanged">
</div>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: use  $scope.$apply()  read it http://jimhoskins.com/2012/12/17/angularjs-and-apply.html

Comment: either that or make sure to .trigger('change')  after the value is updated. Also check if you can see the change in $watch.$scope('period'  .....

Comment: As I understand it the value is changed, but the function in ng-change is not triggered, correct? Could you show your jQuery, unless other comments fixed it

Comment: @CristiMarian .trigger('change') indeed solved my problem. but only after fixing error in ng-change of above code. It should be ng-change="periodChanged()"

Comment: Thanks to all for quick response.